# capturar señal SIGWINCH cliente telnet en reactPHP

Tags: telnet, signals

Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal el reactPHP. En este momento tengo un eventLoop de TcpServer en el que manejo la conexion y dentro de esta, un evento data. Tengo mi propia clase Cursor que maneja ciertos comandos de telnet. De momento tengo esto:

```
$loop = Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\TcpServer('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop);
$socket->on('connection', function (React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $connection) use ($loop) {
    $connection->on('data', function($data) use ($loop, $connection) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = bin2hex($data);
        $connection->write($data.PHP_EOL); // imprimo en cliente
        print_r($data.PHP_EOL); // imprimo en server
    });
    $cursor = new Cursor($connection);
    $cursor->iacDoNaws();
});
```

con esto, cada vez que cambio el tamaño de la terminal, me llega al evento data la informacion de tamaño de pantalla. Hasta aqui bien.

Dado que el cambio de tamaño de pantalla se produce con una signal llamada SIGWING, he pensado en añadir un manejo de signal en el loop:

```
$loop->addSignal(SIGWINCH, $func = function ($signal) use ($loop, &$func) {
    print_r('Signal '.$signal. PHP_EOL);
});
```

El problema es que,aparte que solo atrapa la señal y no la info que se envia (porque no hay un $data), esto solo sucede cuando cambio el tamaño del terminal que actua como servidor. Es logico, porque lo estamos aplicando al $loop, no al $connection. Pero a un $connection no se le puede añadir un addSignal.

Otro problema que plantea el problema anterior es que solo tengo $connection->("data") para manejar TODA la informacion que llega. con lo que si aparece un comando enviado por el terminal, tengo que analizarlo ahi, antes de hacer lo que yo quiera con el data.

Por tanto se me plantean dos preguntas:

es posible aplicar de alguna manera un signal a la conexion, y no solo al servidor?
hay algun evento en el $connection->on(), tipo "preData", en donde pueda analizar la informacion que llega, antes de que salte el "data"?

si no lo hay, entonces solo veo posibilidad de meter un metodo dentro del evento $connection->on('data') que primero evalue lo que llega, y en funcion de si es un comando o no, analizarlo o continuar con el proceso de mi evento...

Alguien puede echarme una mano?